# How do I create the spatter effect in these images also the bottom broken effect?

Tags: adobe-photoshop

[image: How do I create the spatter effect in these images also the bottom broken effect? Ideally i want to be able to add this effect to other images]

How do I create the spatter effect in these images also the bottom broken effect? Ideally I want to be able to add this effect to other images

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Find (or draw) a black silhouette of a city skyline, and a suitable paint splatter image (or paint one with some splatter brushes).

Arrange them in layers in Photoshop as shown below, then apply *Screen* as the layer blending mode (shown circled in red) to the top city skyline layer.

[image]